# CSS animation to repeat every nth second

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations

I am animating a svg element currently like following

```css
.r1 {
     transform-box: fill-box;
     transform-origin: 50% 50%;    
     animation-name: simpleRotation,xRotation;
     animation-delay: 0s, 2s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1, 1;
     animation-timing-function: linear;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes simpleRotation {
     from {
         transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
     to {
         transform: rotate(359deg);
  
    }
}
@keyframes xRotation {
     from {
         transform: rotateX(0deg); 
    }
     to {
         transform: rotateX(359deg); 
    }
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<rect class="r1" id="r1" x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.25" fill="orange"></rect>    
    </svg>
```

Is it possible to queue the animations (with javascript) in a way so that every 2s the animation runs one after another in a loop such as `simpleRotation(0-2s);xRotation(2-4s);simpleRotation(4-6s);xRotation(6-8s);simpleRotation(8-10s);.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to [ccprog's svg SMIL approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71075513/css-animation-to-repeat-every-nth-second/71085128#answer-71081649) might be using the Web Animations API

The keyframe animation can be translated to an animation object like this

```
let ani1 = animEl.animate(
  [{
    transform: "rotate(0deg)"
  }, {
    transform: "rotate(359deg)"
  }], {
    delay: 500,
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1
  }
);
```

See also: [MDN: Using the Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API)

#### Example

```js
let animEl = document.querySelector(".rect1");

let ani1 = animEl.animate(
  [{
    transform: "rotate(0deg)"
  }, {
    transform: "rotate(359deg)"
  }], {
    delay: 500,
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1
  }
);

let ani2 = animEl.animate(
  [{
    transform: "rotateX(0deg)"
  }, {
    transform: "rotateX(359deg)"
  }], {
    delay: 500,
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1,
  }
);
// pause 2. animation
ani2.pause();

// chain animations
ani1.onfinish = function() {
  ani2.play();
};

ani2.onfinish = function() {
  ani1.play();
};
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 10em
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect class="rect1" id="r1" x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.25" fill="orange" transform-origin="50 50" ></rect>
</svg>
```

We pause the second on start animation via

```
 ani2.pause();
```

and add an eventListener to start the second animation after the first one has finished.

```
ani1.onfinish = function() {
  ani2.play();
};
```

**Edit** you could also use [premises as described by Dan Wilson](http://danielcwilson.com/blog/2016/03/animations-and-promises/)

#### Don't miss out on the power of svg's SMIL animation

Especially when it comes to svg related animations, they still offer many bells and whistles not available in css animations like

1. Sequential animations:

   <animate[...] begin="firstAnimation.end" />

The ability to start a consecutive animation (without any calculations of previous duration) via `begin` property is just awesome – this elegant concept should have been adopted to corresponding css animation methods.

2. Move elements along paths
3. self contained animations – like loading spinners
   ... svg wins!

#### Caniuse:

[SMIL animations](https://caniuse.com/?search=smil) tend to have more solid browser support than [Web Animations API](https://caniuse.com/web-animation)
Albeit, it's neglectable due to the grateful retirement of internet explorer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where the [SVG animation](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/) format is easier to use than the CSS keyframe animation - in principle.

SVG animations can define the begin time of an animation in relation to events - among them the end of another animation. This way you can chain animations together, and you can define loops:

```
<animate id="first" begin="0s;second.end" ... />
<animate id="second" begin="first.end" ... />
```

The first animation begins at `0s` and additionally is triggered by the end of the second animation, and the second animation is triggered by the end of the first animation.

The problem with your use case is that you want to animate 3D transform functions. SVG `transform` differs in syntax from CSS `transform`, and does only support 2D transformations. So the following example at best can simulate the effect, and a number of details has to be written in a different manner.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <rect id="r1" x="-5" y="-5" transform="translate(15 15)"
        width="10" height="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.25" fill="orange">
    <animateTransform id="simpleRotation" attributeName="transform" type="rotate"
                      additive="sum" begin="0s;xRotation.end" dur="2s"
                      from="0" to="360" />
    <animateTransform id="xRotation" attributeName="transform" type="scale"
                      additive="sum" begin="simpleRotation.end" dur="2s"
                      values="1 1;1 -1;1 1" keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
                      calcMode="spline" keySplines=".375 0 .375 1;.375 0 .375 1" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

- the center of the animated object is initially placed at `0,0` to simplify the following transforms. Each `<animateTransform>` gets a `additive="sum"` attribute so that it is post-multiplied to the static `translate()` attribute on the animated object.
- to simulate `xRotate()`, a `scale` transform is used that scales the y axis from 1 to -1 and back. Additionally, a spline interpolation is defined to give the impression of a smooth "rotation". Note that this simulation only works in absence of a `perspective`.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is awesome!! However, I don't want to use `SMIL` as I already have CSS animation on other elements. Is it possible to achieve within CSS or by using javascript maybe?